# Working with the `MonadBaseControl` API

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I am currently playing with the Bryan O'Sullivan's [resource-pool](https://github.com/bos/pool) library and have a question regarding extending the `withResource` function.
I want to change the signature of the  `withResource` function from `(MonadBaseControl IO m) => Pool a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` to `(MonadBaseControl IO m) => Pool a -> (a -> m (Bool, b)) -> m b`.
What I want to achieve is, that the action should return `(Bool, b)` tuple, where the boolean value indicates if the borrowed resource should
be put back into the pool or destroyed.

Now my current implementation looks like this:

```
withResource :: forall m a b. (MonadBaseControl IO m) => Pool a -> (a -> m (Bool, b)) -> m b
{-# SPECIALIZE withResource :: Pool a -> (a -> IO (Bool,b)) -> IO b #-}
withResource pool act = fmap snd result
  where
    result :: m (Bool, b)
    result = control $ \runInIO -> mask $ \restore -> do
      resource <- takeResource pool
      ret <- restore (runInIO (act resource)) `onException`
             destroyResource pool resource

      void . runInIO $ do
        (keep, _) <- restoreM ret :: m (Bool, b)

        if keep
          then liftBaseWith . const $ putResource pool resource
          else liftBaseWith . const $ destroyResource pool resource

      return ret
```

And I have a feeling, that this is not how it is supposed to look like...
Maybe I am not using the `MonadBaseControl` API right.
What do you guys think of this and how can I improve it to be more idiomatic?

Comment: A cursory glance looks fine.  What bothers you about it?

Comment: @luqui What bothers me a little bit is, that I have to run `runInIO` twice, which results to more verbose code. Is there a better way to unwrap the `ret` (the result of the first `runInIO` call) inside the IO monad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling that there is a fundamental problem with this approach. For monads for which `StM M a` is equal/isomorphic to `a` it will work. But for other monads there will be a problem. Let's consider `MaybeT IO`. An action of type `a -> MaybeT IO (Bool, b)` can fail, so there will be no `Bool` value produced. And the code in

```
  void . runInIO $ do
    (keep, _) <- restoreM ret :: m (Bool, b)
    ...
```

won't be executed, the control flow will stop at `restoreM`. And for `ListT IO` it'll be even worse, as `putResource` and `destroyResource` will be executed multiple times. Consider this sample program, which is a simplified version of your function:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, ScopedTypeVariables, RankNTypes, TupleSections #-}
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Control
import Control.Monad.Trans.List

foo :: forall m b . (MonadBaseControl IO m) => m (Bool, b) -> m b
foo act = fmap snd result
  where
    result :: m (Bool, b)
    result = control $ \runInIO -> do
      ret <- runInIO act

      void . runInIO $ do
        (keep, _) <- restoreM ret :: m (Bool, b)

        if keep
          then liftBaseWith . const $ putStrLn "return"
          else liftBaseWith . const $ putStrLn "destroy"

      return ret

main :: IO ()
main = void . runListT $ foo f
  where
    f = msum $ map (return . (, ())) [ False, True, False, True ]
```

It'll print

```
destroy
return
destroy
return
```

And for an empty list, nothing gets printed, which means no cleanup would be called in your function.

---

I have to say I'm not sure how to achieve your goal in a better way. I'd try to explore in the direction of signature

```
withResource :: forall m a b. (MonadBaseControl IO m)
             => Pool a -> (a -> IO () -> m b) -> m b
```

where the `IO ()` argument would be a function, that when executed, invalidates the current resource and marks it to be destroyed. (Or, for better convenience, replace `IO ()` with lifted  `m ()`). Then internally, as it's `IO`-based, I'd just create a helper `MVar` that'd be reset by calling
the function, and at the end, based on the value, either return or destroy the resource.

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful answer. I can see now the problems with 'MaybeT' and 'ListT' monads... Thanks again!